# How to know which site/script is taking all CPU and RAM in Plesk/apache

Tags: apache-2.2, ddos, high-load

I have more than 100+ domains on a CentOS Plesk server. Suddenly the load on the server goes very high and eats up all resources. eating up all RAM, all CPU , due to which i cannot even login to server to check that what is happening to server.
I Tried to see the real-time Tail log of all sites, which did not showed anything like there is some external threat.
Mod_Evasive has been installed on the server, which is also not blocking anything.

My question is that how can i know that exactly which Domain/Site/Cron Job or anything in server is eating up all resources.

Note: in the Htop utility, i can see that on top, its httpd which is eating all resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Apache are you using? `mod_evasive` pretty much stopped working for Apache 2.2+. Your first port of call will probably be looking at `httpd status`.

Just run

```
service httpd status
```

at a command line, and it'll give you a real time display of requests, by hostname and IP. You might be observing an attack (e.g. one where an attacker keeps a large number of connections open at the same time).

If that doesn't work, add these lines to your `httpd.conf`:

```
<Location /server-status>
   SetHandler server-status
   Order Deny,Allow
   Deny from all
   Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Location>
```

Cyberciti has a [good article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/apache-server-status/) on it. The next thing you could try would be

```
netstat -ntu | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

> The command below creates a list of IP addresses connected to the server, along with their total number of connections.

(paraphrased, from [DDos Deflate](http://deflate.medialayer.com/)). After running both of these, you begin to be able to see if you're under attack, or a single website is just consuming a disproportionate amount of CPU.

Comment: You probably also want `ExtendedStatus On`.  The normal `mod_status` output doesn't tell you enough.